# How to check how many specific results is in name indexed array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I'd like to check how many elements with name: "order" have value equal 1.

my array:

```
var myArray=[{"index":1,"zamid":"765","prod":"Spaghetti","price":"22","prod_c":"1","order":"1"},
{"index":2,"zamid":"766","prod":"Coca","price":"5","prod_c":"1","order":"0"},
{"index":3,"zamid":"767","prod":"Hamburger","price":"6","prod_c":"1","order":"1"}]
```

thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function (using arrow functions):

```
let count = myArray.filter(i => i.order === "1").length;
```

ES5 alternative:

```
var count = myArray.filter(function(i) {
    return i.order === "1";
}).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

One array method is missing: [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var myArray = [{ "index": 1, "zamid": "765", "prod": "Spaghetti", "price": "22", "prod_c": "1", "order": "1" }, { "index": 2, "zamid": "766", "prod": "Coca", "price": "5", "prod_c": "1", "order": "0" }, { "index": 3, "zamid": "767", "prod": "Hamburger", "price": "6", "prod_c": "1", "order": "1" }],
    count = myArray.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r + (a.order === '1');
    }, 0);

document.write(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.filter`

```js
var myArray = [{
  "index": 1,
  "zamid": "765",
  "prod": "Spaghetti", 
  "price": "22",
  "prod_c": "1",
  "order": "1"
}, {
  "index": 2,
  "zamid": "766",
  "prod": "Coca",
  "price": "5",
  "prod_c": "1",
  "order": "0"
}, {
  "index": 3,
  "zamid": "767",
  "prod": "Hamburger",
  "price": "6",
  "prod_c": "1",
  "order": "1"
}]

var result = [];

result = myArray.filter(function(obj){
  return obj.order == 1
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: May as well just look for `"1"`

Comment: Have got rid of `parseInt`, though have used evil `==`

Answer (score 0):

Define the "outer" counter and check the array with `forEach`:

```
var counter = 0;
var myArray=[{"index":1,"zamid":"765","prod":"Spaghetti","price":"22","prod_c":"1","order":"1"},
{"index":2,"zamid":"766","prod":"Coca","price":"5","prod_c":"1","order":"0"},
{"index":3,"zamid":"767","prod":"Hamburger","price":"6","prod_c":"1","order":"1"}];

myArray.forEach(function(obj){
   if(obj.order == 1) counter++;
});

console.log(counter); // output: 2
```